# Get request header from freemarker

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, freemarker, request-headers

I want to create AJAX-navigation on my site with `Freemarker` as template engine.
If page are requested with `XMLHttpRequest`, there is no need to include page header and footer. Code will be look like this:

```
[#if !XMLHttpRequest]
    [#include "header.ftl"]
[/#if]
${content}
[#if !XMLHttpRequest]
    [#include "footer.ftl"]
[/#if]
```

My question is how to define that the request came with AJAX. Client adds header X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest, and how do I get it in Freemarker?
I tried to find it in [HttpRequestHashModel](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/servlet/HttpRequestHashModel.html):

```
[#assign XMLHttpRequest = Request.headers['X-Requested-With']=="XMLHttpRequest" /]
```

but it throws error `Expression Request.headers is undefined`. I also tried to use RequestParameters it can't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeMarker itself doesn't define any HTTP related variables; it's not like JSP, it's a general purpose engine; it only sees variables that were passed to it, and it doesn't know what they are... they are just name-value pairs as far as FreeMarker is concerned. So if you need this information, then either you should pass it to FreeMarker in the actions (maybe globally with a filter or interceptor or whatever you have), or the web application framework should.

Comment: Thanks. I had to write own custom FreeMarkerView where request headers puts to template model and my issue has been resolved.