# How I examine a HTTP Request to index.ftl?

Tags: jsp, struts2, freemarker

I want to examine some request in FTL file. In example if it was in jsp;

```
    String deneme  = request.getHeader("Content-Type") + " This is from req.header";
    if(deneme.contains("multipart")) {
        // ...  
    }
```

But I want to write like this code in FTL file. Some code of my Index.ftl

```
Your name: <@s.url value="${name}"/>
Enter your name here:<br/>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I intend to examine a HTTP request which had a name parameter in index.ftl file.

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17650243/3511123

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know Struts, but somewhere in the action (i.e. controller) you should be able to get the request headers and set them in a variable, that is then passed to your freemarker template (i.e. view).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try it

Comment: You should learn variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868476/573032